# Как записывать данные с микрофона в Си linux

Tags: linux, c, аудио

OS: Linux
Lang: C
Как записывать аудио с микрофона в файл, а позже воспроизводить звук
Используя API Linux?

Comment: используя апи линукс не удобно. используй SDL

Comment: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/34_audio_recording/index.php